# Load chart pie inside div when it is in viewpoint

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using [easypiechart plugin](http://rendro.github.io/easy-pie-chart/) and I want it to load it only when the user scrolls down to the .skills div. I am using the [viewport plugin](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/viewport).

I've tried like this:

```
<script src="js/viewport.js"></script>
<script>
    (function(){
    if ($(".skills:in-viewport")){
    jQuery.getScript("js/jquery.easypiechart.min.js").done(function() {
        $('.chart').easyPieChart({
            easing: 'easeOutBounce',
            onStep: function(from, to, percent) {
                $(this.el).find('.percent').text(Math.round(percent));
            }
        });
    });
    };
    });
    </script>
```

It does not show when it is in viewpoint.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it without the viewport plugin. You can use `$(window).height()` and when the user scrolls down you check if the distance of the `div` where you want the chart is less than the scrolled distance + `$(window).height()`, if so you draw it.

Here is the code:

```
var el = document.getElementById('your-div'),
    topDistance = el.getBoundingClientRect().top,
    drawn = false;

function drawPieChart() {
    jQuery.getScript("js/jquery.easypiechart.min.js").done(function() {
        $('.chart').easyPieChart({
            easing: 'easeOutBounce',
            onStep: function(from, to, percent) {
                $(this.el).find('.percent').text(Math.round(percent));
            }
        });
    });
}

function handleScroll() {
    if (document.body.scrollTop + $(window).height() > topDistance) {
        drawn || drawPieChart();
        drawn = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Marco Bonelli Will it be mobile friendly?

Comment: @Bhaiya yes (also depending on the piechart lib)